# Textarea заходит за рамки ! CSS

Tags: bootstrap, css

Как сделать ограничение на растяжение textarea ? указав свои значения ? не могу никак сделать, точнее могу, но при изменении размеров textarea сползает)

P.S. На скриншоте видите, что можно растянуть textarea куда угодно...

Скриншот: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте стили css textarea **width** или **padding**

для отмены ресайза -

```
textarea{
 resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду в самом boostrap.min.css, то там все отлично проверял.

Comment: ну мне нужно что бы в низ resize был, а в бок нет. Т.е я думаю это так, max-width:0%; max-height: value %; Но опять же не получиться сделать. Если делать в пикселях, то получиться, но сам элемент сползет при масштабировании страницы.

Comment: тогда resize: vertical